# Analyzing heap dump, Map#size() is not a function?

Tags: java, heap-memory, visualvm, oql

Getting this weird error:

`javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: size is not a function, it is null. (#1)`

While analyzing a heap dump and running this OQL query on VisualVM:

```
select { map: x } 
from java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap x 
where x.size() < 10
```

The problem lies on the `where` clause, somehow it's not working though `Map` obviously has a size method.

Answer (score 3):

@ruakh's answer is preety good, except one little thing. A segment sometimes could be null, which messes up `sum(x.segments, 'it.count')`. Replace it with

```
sum(x.segments, 'it != null ? it.count : 0')
```

and it will work fine. Tested upon my word.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through [the VisualVM OQL documentation](http://visualvm.java.net/oqlhelp.html), I don't get the impression that it supports Java method calls, only Java fields. (Some of their examples include `.toString()`, but that's clearly the JavaScript `.toString()` rather than the Java one, since they use it to convert a Java `String` object to a JavaScript string.) So, for example, their length-of-a-string examples all use the private field `count` rather than the public method `length()`, and their length-of-a-vector example uses the private field `elementCount` rather than the public method `size()`.

So the error you're getting is because `ConcurrentHashMap` has no field named `size`.

Unfortunately for your query, `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't store its size in a field — that would compromise its ability to avoid blocking — so I think you'll have to write something like this:

```
select { map: x }
from java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap x
where sum(x.segments, 'it.count') < 10
```

to sum all the segment-sizes yourself. (Disclaimer: 100% completely untested.)

Comment: oops - my previous urls got mangled a bit somehow: i meant http://eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/564977/ and http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/3655/  (the ending slashes make all the difference.)

Comment: @BrianHenry: Ah, O.K.; those pages are infinitely relevant-er, thanks. (Why does a slash make such a difference? Who writes Web software that way?!)

Comment: i've not seen something quite like it before.  but why it's written that way is perhaps a question for another stackoverflow post...